# How to check hard drives info on HP-UX?

Tags: unix, hp-ux

I am new to UNIX systems and so far i know only basic shell commands.

Can someone tell me how to check the available hard drives on my server and get an info on them? I am also searching for a command to check their firmware version as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On HP-UX you can easily use the `sam` (System Administration Manager) utility to check all sorts of infos about hardware and software configuration. There is a GUI version and a cli one, sam is kind of a one-in-all thing.

For disk firmware status and upgrades and lower level info use the STM (Support Tools Manager) that you can DL from HP's nice and wonderful page.

Depending on the machine (Integrity or old PA-RISC based stuff) you can also go the EFI route, to place the disk image firmware on the EFI partition and hack things via the built-in EFI shell.

Comment: Thank you Pfo. I didn't knew about the SAM I guess I will try it now :)

Answer (score 1):

SAM is deprecated as of 11.31, use SMH (system management homepage) instead.

Using command line:

Disk available on a system:

```
ioscan -fnNkCdisk #11.31
ioscan -fnkCdisk #pre-11.31
```

Disk type and size info:

```
diskinfo /dev/rdsk/c?t?d? #pre-11.31
diskinfo /dev/rdisk/disk123 # 11.31
```

Comment: The system for which I asked was also deprecated, as it was HP-UX 11.00 ;)

Thanks for answering thou, as I will keep this in mind for other versions. :)

Comment: The pre-11.31 commands should work on 11.00.